# Method overriding rules in Dart

Tags: dart, oop

Please look at the code below:

```
void main() {
  Child c = new Child();
  c.m1("12");
}

class Parent {
  void m1(int a) {
    print("value of a $a");
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  @override
  void m1(String b) {
    print("value of b $b");
  }
}
```

When I run the program, it shows me the following error message:

`Error: The parameter 'b' of the method 'Child.m1' has type 'String', which does not match the corresponding type, 'int', in the overridden method, 'Parent.m1'. Change to a supertype of 'int', or, for a covariant parameter, a subtype.`

I didn't quite understand this error message. What are the conditions of overriding a method in dart?
Probably I cannot change the data type while overriding the function. Is it?

Comment: That is correct, sir.  Was just gonna be simply "yes", but SO wanted more text. :)  Well, technically, you can make the data-type narrower, but not wider, and not unrelated.

Comment: The rule is: is the overriding function *substitutable* for the original base function?  That is, does the overriding function satisfy the interface of the base function?  If you have `Parent maybeChild = Child();`, what would you expect to happen when calling `maybeChild.m1(42)`? Also see the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz An overriding function can make a *parameter*'s data type wider and a *return* type narrower.  A parameter's data type cannot be narrower and a return type cannot be wider (without sacrificing type-safety) because that would violate the interface of the base class.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew the moment I wrote those, I was probably getting it backwards. :)